# Does Kudu have requirements on the block size of the file system?

Tags: filesystems, kudu, xfs

When initializing Kudu, will check if the file system supports punch hole. Kudu will create a test file when initailizing and do puch hole, and [check if the file's size is what we'd expect.](https://github.com/apache/kudu/blob/83cec9c1ecdd17967bef39f9d990c9c31dc4302c/src/kudu/fs/dir_util.cc#L101C3-L101C3)
However, kudu [use 4k offset to test punch hole](https://github.com/apache/kudu/blob/83cec9c1ecdd17967bef39f9d990c9c31dc4302c/src/kudu/fs/dir_util.cc#L68). On xfs, kudu use [XFS_IOC_UNRESVSP64](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/xfsctl.3.html) to do punch hole, if block_size > 4k, XFS_IOC_UNRESVSP64 will just make the first filesystem block partially zeroed, and don't remove the first block from the file, so that the puch hole check will fail because the file's size isn't what we'd expect.
[image]